# Compare Time: It is 7am, what time is closer 5am or 10am?

Tags: php, date, time, compare

I am trying to compare times and I'm not entirely sure the best way to handle this.

I have an array of times that is un-able to edit. 
array("500", "1100", "1700", "2300");

500 = 5:00am etc...

If it is 6 or 7am, what kind of logic can I run to find out if it is 7am, what time is closer 5am or 10am?

I don't think it's complex, but i'm just trying to figure out a decent solution vs. me trying to hack something together.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The math becomes more interesting for values `"0550", "0615"` - which is closer to 6:00? I would recommend first normalizing to a fractional unit - e.g. 5:50 is 5.83 - if it's only needing to see which is closer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the array you have:

```
$values = array("500", "1100", "1700", "2300");
```

What we want is to format it to a valid time string, that is easy, we just insert ":" in the right position. For that I created a function:

```
function Format($str)
{
    $length = strlen($str);
    return substr($str, 0, $length - 2).':'.substr($str, $length - 2);
}
```

Now we can get valid string that we can convert to unix time with [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). The problem now is to find the closer to the current time (which we get with [time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php))

So, we can iterate over the array, convert them, calculate the difference with the current time (in absolute value) and pick the one that results in a lower number. Here is the code:

```
$now = time(); //current time
$best = false;
$bestDiff = 0;
for ($index = 0; $index < count($values); $index++)
{
    $diff = abs($now - strtotime(Format($values[$index])));
    if ($best === false || $diff < $bestDiff)
    {
        $best = $index;
        $bestDiff = $diff;
    }
}
```

It will leave the index of the closer time in `$best` and the difference with the moment of the computation in `$bestDiff`. Please note that this is all asumming that those times are in the same day and local time.

Answer (score 2):

I adapted Theraot's solution to sort the array by the value's distance to the current time:

```
<?php
$values = array("500", "1100", "1700", "2300");
$now = time();

/**
 *  Format an integer-string to a date-string
 */
function format($str)
{
    $length = strlen($str);
    return substr($str, 0, $length - 2).':'.substr($str, $length - 2);
}

/**
 * Callback to compare the distance to now for two entries in $values
 */
$compare = function ($timeA, $timeB) use ($now) {
    $diffA = abs($now - strtotime(format($timeA)));
    $diffB = abs($now - strtotime(format($timeB)));
    if ($diffA == $diffB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($diffA < $diffB) ? -1 : 1;
};

usort($values, $compare);

print_r($values);
```

Your desired result is in $values[0] now.
Note that this solution requires php version >= 5.3

Answer (score 0):

the absolute value of the difference between two times

say 07:00 - 05:00 = 02:00, absolute value of 02:00 is still 02:00

07:00 - 10:00 = -03:00, absolute value of -03:00 is 03:00

In PHP you can convert your time-string to seconds using strtotime:

```
$time_one = strtotime("07:00");
$time_two = strtotime("05:00");
$time_three = strtotime("09:00");
```

Comment: But how do you do "0700" - "0500"?

Comment: Whenever you use strtotime() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php you'll get your time mentioned in the string returned in seconds since epoch. That's a numerical number which can be used to do your calculations

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
// Input data
$values = array("500", "1100", "1700", "2300");
$time = "12:15";

// turns search time to timestamp
$search = strtotime($time);

// turns "500" to "5:00" and so on
$new = preg_replace('/^(\d?\d)(\d\d)$/','\1:\2', $values);

// converts the array to timestamp
$new = array_map('strtotime', $new);

// sorts the array (just in case)
asort($new);

// Some initialization
$distance = $closest = $result = $result_index = NULL;

// The search itself
foreach($new as $idx => $time_stamp)
{
        $distance = abs($time_stamp - $search);
        if(is_null($closest) OR $closest > $distance)
        {
                $closest = $distance;
                $result_index = $idx;
                $result = $time_stamp;

        }
}
echo "The closest to $time is ".date('H:i', $result)." ({$values[$result_index]})";
```